# Subsetting a table using a matrix

Tags: r, subset

I'm getting started with R and I'm having problems with a n-dimensional table `my.table` which I want to subset in various ways. I have a row matrix `m` that lets me pick a single cell of the table with `my.table[m]`. Now I want to use `m` to select a whole row of the table (not only one cell) by indicating one dimension `i` which I don't want to be sliced. This can be easily done with normal indexing by leaving the `i`-th position of the index empty, but in my case the value of `i` is only known at runtime.

I'll try to illustrate it with some code:

```
# let's assume n = 4
# I can pick a cell value with the literal indexing
a.value <- my.table[2, 1, 4, 2]
# And I can reproduce this with matrix indexing
m <- matrix(c(2, 1, 4, 2), nrow=1)
a.value <- my.table[m]

# Now let's assume i = 3
# I can subset the table with literal indexing to pick the whole row
a.row <- my.table[2, 1, , 2]
# But how can I do the same using the matrix m?
```

I have tried setting `m[i] <- NA` and `m[i] <- NULL`, but obviously it does not work.

Is there some "magical" value equivalent to the empty space in a literal index? Or there is no way of doing this straightforwardly?

UPDATE:

I'll post the code that I am using by now that gives the result I want. Still, it would be great to know if there is a better, more elegant or more general way to do it:

```
function(my.table, m, i) {
    i.dim <- dim(my.table)[i]
    return(apply(matrix(1:i.dim, nrow=1), 1, function(x) {
        # in my case, I don't need to preserve the original value of m[i]
        m[i] <- x
        return(my.table[m])
    }))
}
```

UPDATE 2:
As requested by @javlacalle, I'm posting the output of `dput` of the table.

```
structure(c(0.830412306140461, 0.169587693859539, 0.944833625218914, 
0.0551663747810858, 0.993589743589744, 0.00641025641025641, 1, 
0, 0.992307692307692, 0.00769230769230769, 1, 0, 1, 0, NaN, NaN
), class = "table", .Dim = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    V29.0 = c("0", "1"), `779.89` = c("0", "1"), `771.81` = c("0", 
    "1"), `771.89` = c("0", "1")), .Names = c("V29.0", "779.89", 
"771.81", "771.89")))
```

UPDATE 3:

I've found out that the "magical" value I was talking about actually exists, you can get it with `bquote()` - only that I don't think there is a way to use it along with other numbers in a matrix to form a proper index.

Comment: Have your tried `m[i,] <- NA`? This will set all the elements in the i-th row to NAs. Is that what you want?

Comment: @javlacalle No, actually `m` is just one row. I want to be able to select a row in `my.table` my giving concrete values to every dimension of the table except `i`. I will edit the question to explain it better.

Comment: please post the output from `dput(my.table)` and the values that you want to select.

Comment: If I do `f(my.table, m, 2)` I get an error because the argument `MARGIN` is not defined when you use `apply`. How do you use this function to get the result?

Comment: @javlacalle Sorry, no, I just made a function extracting the code from my script, I'll fix it.

Comment: @javlacalle Aaghhh data types >:( it's still wrong, I'm on it

Comment: You may define the expression that you want as character and then evaluate it. For example, `eval(parse(text="my.table[2,1,,2]"))`. In this way you just need to worry about defining a character string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about writing e.g. `my.table[1, 1, 1, 1:2]` instead of `my.table[1, 1, 1, ]`?
You could set the indices that you want to be expanded to  0 (in `m`)  and then define

```
f <- function(my.table, m) {
    dims <- dim(my.table)
    a <- lapply(1:4, function(x) if (m[, x] == 0) 1:dims[x] else m[, x])
    my.table[a[[1]], a[[2]], a[[3]], a[[4]]]
}
```

For example

```
m <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 0), nrow = 1)
my.table[, 1, 1, ] # same as my.table[1:2, 1, 1, 1:2]
#      771.89
# V29.0         0           1
#     0 0.8304123 0.992307692
#     1 0.1695877 0.007692308

f(my.table, m)
#      771.89
# V29.0         0           1
#     0 0.8304123 0.992307692
#     1 0.1695877 0.007692308
```

Comment: I wanted to know if the language provided some construct to do it directly without any helper function, but I assume it doesn't. Your solution is quite good though, so I'll accept it as correct answer.